# More than one taglib sharing same parameter in JSF 2.1

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I created a custom taglib (JSF 2.1) with .xhtml and a view scoped managed bean.

Inside the taglib I use a parameter to print a buy button like this:

```
<ui:composition>
<ui:param name="complement" value="_#{catId}_#{prdId}" />
<h:form id="formRating#{complement}">
    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
        <h:panelGrid>
            <p:commandButton action="#{BuyBean.buy(catId, prdId)}" value="Buy" update="formRating#{complement}" />
            <h:outputText value="#{BuyBean.getTotal(catId, prdId)}" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

It works fine only when I call this taglib once. If I call two or more times, he always pass the same parameters to "buy".

```
<myTaglib:customTaglib catId="1" prdId="2" />
<myTaglib:customTaglib catId="3" prdId="4" />
<myTaglib:customTaglib catId="5" prdId="6" />
```

It results with 3 buttons calling "buy" with "1" and "2" as arguments.

Is this the right behavior or am I missing something?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's not the right behaviour. You've apparently a bug or a coding mistake in your custom taglib. But we can't point out that as you haven't posted any relevant code behind your custom taglib.

Comment: Thanks, @BalusC. I have edited the question with the tag.

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. This tag behavior is completely correct. What was wrong was my .xhtml calling it that was passing another parameter list. Can I mark this as resolved even without answer?